# JSR223 Postprocessor to parse json in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, jsr223

I have used BSF Postprocessor to parse json in one of my jmeter test files. My code is as follow.

```
eval('var response = '+prev.getResponseDataAsString());
vars.put("userAccountID", response.ID);
```

But i have found that BSF post processor reduces Jmeter's performance. So i am going for JSR223 Post processor. I need to know what is the corresponding code for above in JSR223 (JAVA language). Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use jsr223 assertion and javascript. Then you can just simply check and parse your data. for example:

```
var response = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
var jsonOutput = JSON.parse(response);
```

Now you can simply operate on "jsonOutput".

**#UPDATE#**

Looks like in new JMeter version using javascript is deprecated because of performance and lack of options to manipulate data.
(Back then when i was test developer my example had been working just fine; thats why i show it here)
Probably better option is to migrate to Groovy:
http://michalsi.github.io/performance-tests/2018/01/08/jmter-working-with-json.html

Comment: `JSON` does not seem to be available by default: `Problem in JSR223 script, Set $SIGNATURE_ID, DOCUMENT_ID
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JSON for class: Script241`

Comment: as i know; in new jmeter javascript is kind of deprecated so maybe you should migrate to groovy.
http://michalsi.github.io/performance-tests/2018/01/08/jmter-working-with-json.html

Comment: I'm using `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(String)` in Groovy, which works fine. It just feels clunky :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-box support of JSON in Java SE hence sample code will depend on JSON library for Java you choose.

May I suggest take a look at [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) Post Processor instead? It is designed to parse JSON data and doesn't require any scripting.

For more information on the JSON Path Extractor see [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON" section)